# SQL - How to includes row with zero results with a WHERE condition

Tags: mysql, sql, count, left-join

I have a query for selecting the number of people who reserved a specific hotel on all dates available.

Basically, I have two tables:

- ***dates_event*** which list all the dates available in which I have 3 dates
- ***registered_hotels*** which list the registrations from all people with the according hotel, date and user id

The trick is I want to display '0' if no-one reserved the hotel for a specific day.

Here is my query :

```
SELECT dates_event.date_full, count(registered_hotels.id_registered)
FROM dates_event 
    LEFT JOIN registered_hotels ON dates_event.date_id = registered_hotels.date_id
    WHERE registered_hotels.idhotel='1'
    GROUP by dates_event.date_full
```

It displays this :

```
+-------------+----------------------------------------+
|  date_full  | count(registered_hotels.id_registered) |
+-------------+----------------------------------------+
| 2019-09-15  |                                      1 |
| 2019-09-16  |                                      1 |
+-------------+----------------------------------------+
```

While I want to display this:

```
+-------------+----------------------------------------+
|  date_full  | count(registered_hotels.id_registered) |
+-------------+----------------------------------------+
| 2019-09-15  |                                      1 |
| 2019-09-16  |                                      1 |
| 2019-09-17  |                                      0 |
+-------------+----------------------------------------+
```

I found answers to actually display the zero but nothing when I have a specific WHERE condition that seem to let out all empty rows.

Any idea on how I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put your `registered_hotels.idhotel='1'` in on condition instead of where

```
SELECT dates_event.date_full, count(registered_hotels.id_registered)
FROM dates_event 
    LEFT JOIN registered_hotels ON dates_event.date_id = registered_hotels.date_id
    and registered_hotels.idhotel='1'
    GROUP by dates_event.date_full
```

Comment: Well, that was quick, that worked well ! Thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: Sure, you were so quick I have to wait 10 min :)